# Python - How can I use a variable defined in one module across other modules

Tags: python

I am stuck on one concept in my automation project using selenium webdriver with python. I have a created a module which contains a script for Login. Now I want to use the variable declared in Login.py into other test cases. I used import module feature in other scripts. But the script fails with **variable not found** error.

Below is an easy representation of the scenario :

1)Sample.py

```
class Integers():
    def Sum(self):
        a=6
        b=3
        print(a+b)
inst = Integers()
inst.Sum()
```

2) Test.py

```
import Sample
print(a)
```

when I run Test.py,  it fails with error:

> NameError: name 'a' is not defined.

Can someone help me out? Am I missing something? I have just started in Python and got stuck here

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I would recommend that you study basic Python before you get involved with Selenium. Also, this problem has nothing to do with selenium itself, so consider removing that tag,

Comment: You don't have `a` in `Test.py`. And you don't even have `a` in `Sample.py`! Start reading manuals.

Comment: @VikasDamodar What does this have to do with selenium?

Comment: @VikasDamodar You really should not give such terrible advises to newbies - that's the worst possible way to "solve" the op's problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You obviously not only "just started in Python" but actually "just started programming". In your snippet, `a` is a local variable in a function. Local variables only exist during a function execution and cannot be accessed from anywhere outside the function itself. This - the notion of variable's scope - is really one of the very basic concepts in programming.

If you want to make a value defined in function available to other code, the usual solution is to return that variable from the function:

```
# lib.py
def askusername():
    username = input("username ?")
    return username
```

and then:

```
# main.py
import lib
username = lib.askusername()
```

Answer (score 0):

If `a` has a constant value, you should define it as a static member of `Integers`:

```
class Integers:
    a = 1
    def Sum():
        print(Integers.a + 5)
```

Then you can write `print(YourModule.Integers.a)` in your 'test.py' file after importing the class `Integers`.